Cannot generate migrations diff after update
I made some updates to my symfony app:

PHP 7.4 to 8.3
Symfony 5.4 to 6.4
API Platform 2.x to 3

In the process I deleted FOSUserBundle I was using. It ended with some updates to the mysql database. I’m using Doctrine migrations and I have hardtime to generate them.
If I’m running bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff, a migration class is generated but up and down are empty.
However if I’m running bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql I can see the updates I made to the database.
Is it normal? How to fix it?

The command you want is bin/console make:migration. https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5-doctrine/migrations

pretty sure that’s just a shortcut to doctrine:migrations:generate anyway it produces the same, still nothing

it isn't. but do what you like.

The reason was <up> and <down> in my template were never replaced by my custom generator and I still don’t know why.
